# CodeSynthesis XML with C++ TCP socket

Tags: c++, xml, sockets, tcp, tcpsocket

I'm not really experienced with C++ so I need to ask you for some help.

I need a server implemented in C++ that listens to a TCP port. On this port it should simply receive XML documents. I found several multi-threaded TCP socket examples, but I have no idea how to take care about ReadToEnd or converting into a string or XML document.

I was thinking to use [CodeSynthesis](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/c++/tree/) that works with streams. But how to combine the TCP socket and a stream?

Sorry if this sounds like a noob question. But I appreciate any good example or advise.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I used

- [CodeSynthesis XSD/e](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsde/) and
- [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html).

The boost lib provides a nice socket abstraction layer and input/output streams which can be used for serializing and deserializing XML documents with CodeSynthesis afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Tcp protocol itself does not give you the way to distinct one message from another. It guarantee only order and that no data will be undelivered.
So it is up to you to implement ReadToEnd function. For example you can send some special symbol ( making sure first it is not presented in your xmls ). Or you can use already existing http protocol to send multiple documents through one connection. You can try http://libevent.org/ http server implementation and use it for your needs.
Even simpler way will be to use existing http web server and receive your documents with it, in this case you don't need to create your own.

Comment: I need the XML document in memory and parse it in my application. So I guess using a WebServer is not of help here, or? And I know about TCP protocol and worked with it in C# a lot. But I'm going crazy working in C++. This is why I'm asking for any example how a string or method or other structed data is read from a TCP socket.